# Google Play Services and Firebase conflicts

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I want to use both firebase and google play services dependencies. But it causes some conflictings. When i add the play services dependency, then firebase dependency does not work. Do you know how to use both dependencies at the same time? Thank you.

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
```

into this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Versions of com.google.android.gms:* and com.google.firebase:* dependencies prior to 15.0.0 had to be at the same version.  After 15.0.0, this is no longer the case.  See https://developers.google.com/android/guides/versioning for more details.

It should be noted, you should also no longer use the com.google.android.gms:play-services catch-all monolithic target as this includes **all** Google Play services and Firebase libraries into your project, bloating your app unnecessarily as you are unlikely to need to use all targets.  This usage had been discouraged for some time and was actually removed in v15.0.0 (https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#april_12_2018_-_version_1500)